# Fixed footer not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am using jQuery mobile 1.1.1 for my app.
My `index.html` looks like:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">
   <div data-role="content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" align="center">                            
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer_fixed">   
    <div ><a href="#surveyConductedList"  class="ui-link" > List </a></div>
    <div ><a href="#uploadData"  class="ui-link" > Upload </a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the footer:

```css
.footer_fixed {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom:0;
}
```

But my footer does not display on screen. It displays very last at the end of screen. I want to stick it on screen and move down as I scroll down

Comment: what is `footer-fixed` in your css?

Comment: it is in jquery.mobile.1.1.1.css file which applies css to data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"

Comment: there is no `ui-footer-fixed` class in your provided html

Comment: sorry but i can not display all content of index file but same css is applied to page i checked in chrome

Comment: then you should create [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), put your content there and share a link here :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make it with an [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

```
[data-role="footer"] {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

or add a class to your `footer` because you do not have any class that references to `.ui-footer-fixed`.

**Edit:** If you want to set your footer to the bottom (as a `footer` normally is) you have to set `bottom: 0;` as `@thepio` points out. I did not add it before because I wanted to maintain your `CSS` code but I add here to avoid doubts.

Comment: Should it not also have `bottom: 0;` ?

Comment: @thepio Yes, I also think so, but I am waiting until he adds more data to his question or says that something more brokes so I maintain his code by the moment.

Comment: @thepio Anyway I added it to avoid doubts :)

Comment: ok now i changed my code added class in head section..but still problem is same..my page size is bigger than screen size and i want to display footer at bottom as i scroll down

Comment: in my sony mobile code works fine but  in all other mobiles footer directly show at bottom where page content ends

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to see better the problem that you are having? Also, can you post a working example of code please? A good place to put code and execute it is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I got source of my problem there is another css file who apply css to that page like--  backface-visibility: hidden;transform: translate3d(0,0,0);perspective: 1000;  and i could not detect it on chrome ...

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Comment: @beginneratprogramming You are most welcome. I am glad that you finally solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

when u keep it fixed then it cant b move down like scrol down you are saying .'
when u keep it fixed then it will fixed to that place

use other kind of position like relative or absolute to moving it down
check this 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. Position absolute or relative won't "stick it" at the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: he is saying move down like a scrol so he cant use fixed